# What is the common expression to describe position starting from the last one?

Tags: expression-choice

Suppose we have letters: a, b, c, d, e, f ,g.

I want to describe the position of letter "e" starting from right hand side, what should I use?

"e" is the last third letter.

"e" is the third last letter.

"e" is the last but two letters.

Which one is commonly used? Or other ways to describe it?

Thanks!

Comment: The only one of your suggestions which is right is `"e" is the third last letter` (though `third from last` is better.) For your third example, you could say `"e" is the last letter but two` (note  letter is singular) but even then it is a little strange and confusing. Your first example `"e" is the last third letter` could only make sense if you wanted to say that there is a list of words of which you are interested in the third letter, and "e" is the third letter of the last word. English Language Learners stack exchange may be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Typically you'd expect to hear:

> "e" is the third **from** last letter

or

> "e" is the third **to** last letter

and you may sometimes hear

> "e" is the last but two

Comment: It could also be "2 from last" and probably "second from last" depending on who you ask.

Comment: @Jodrell is that a British thing? I'd expect "third"; "2/second from last" always means penultimate.

Comment: As a Brit, I would say 3rd from last.

Comment: I cede that "second from last" is more erroneous than ambiguous, but "2/two from last" clearly confuses things.

Comment: As a Brit, I’d would usually just say “the third last letter”, no preposition required.

Comment: You could also say "third from the end".

Answer (score 15):

The common usage would be *"third to last"*. If you need a weird word, use *[antepenultimate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antepenultimate)* or *[propenultimate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/propenultimate)*:

> "Two before the last, i.e., the one immediately before the penultimate, in a series."
>
> This book has ten chapters — chapter 8 is the antepenultimate one.

(From Wiktionary)

Comment: +1 for "if you need a weird word" :)

Comment: But _antepenultimate_ doesn't generalize to other positions, does it? Can you keep adding prefixes, so the previous one is _anteantepenultimate_?

Comment: @Barmar: [*preantepenultimate*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preantepenultimate#Adjective) :-)

Comment: (pre)antepenultimate tends to be used in linguistics when describing the position of stress in a word (or short phrase) so there has generally not been the need to invent a long series of these. I think propreantepenultimate would not be widely understood and I know of nothing earlier than that.

Answer (score 2):

Antepenultimate means before the next to last.